# Как при открытии файла получить ссылку на него?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

У меня в проекте на C++ есть возможность сохранять изменённые данные в файл, но есть проблема, когда я открываю не саму программу, а ее файл, то мне нужно считывать все, что в нем находится. Как получить ссылку (C://.../*.tst), при открытии файла по клику на него.

Answer (score 1):

Если тип файлов ассоциирован с вашей программой (это можно установить в вручную: правый клик по файлу -> Открыть с помощью -> Выбрать программу), то при нажатии на файл запустится ваша программа. Вторым аргументом командной строки будет путь к файлу.

Получить этот аргумент можно двумя способами. Если у вас консольная программа, то параметр `argv[1]` в функции main() будет содержать ссылку на файл.
Если же у вас программа с графическим интерфейсом и включен режим UNICODE, то используйте функции `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW`:

```
LPWSTR *szArglist;
int nArgs;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);
// Здесь szArglist[1] будет содержать путь к файлу
```

Если вы хотите программно ассоциировать расширение файла с вашей программой, то это более сложно, уточните вопрос.